# How can a blender object inside a collection be turned active using python scripting?

Tags: python, blender

I want to choose an object located in a collection

obviously the following command doesn't work:

```
    bpy.data.objects[plankname].select_set(True)
```

This is since the object is not part of the main scene

Answer (score 0):

```
bpy.data.collections["CollectionName"].objects["ObjectName"].select_set(True)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to provide some context and explanation of how this code answers the question.